# SQL Server 2012 Trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hey guys thank you in advance for any help,
I have this trigger in my SQL Server 2012 database

```
    USE Teste_TextMining
CREATE TRIGGER Noticia07032016 ON dbo.textos
AFTER INSERT
AS
DECLARE @ID INT
SET @ID = (     SELECT MAX(ID_texto) FROM dbo.textos)
DECLARE @tag NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @tag = (    SELECT TOP 1 keyphrase 
                FROM semantickeyphrasetable(textos, *)
                WHERE document_key=@ID)
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.textos
    SET tag = UPPER(@tag) 
    WHERE ID_texto = @ID
END
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.textos
    SET data = GETDATE()
    WHERE ID_texto = @ID
END
GO
```

And as you can see it should update 2 values the "tag" row and the "data" row once something is inserted in the table, however its only updating the "data" row.

If i just select this piece of code and run/debug it, it actually updates both rows, any idea why this is hapening ?

```
DECLARE @ID INT
    SET @ID = (     SELECT MAX(ID_texto) FROM dbo.textos)
    DECLARE @tag NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @tag = (    SELECT TOP 1 keyphrase 
                    FROM semantickeyphrasetable(textos, *)
                    WHERE document_key=@ID)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.textos
        SET tag = UPPER(@tag) 
        WHERE ID_texto = @ID
    END
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.textos
        SET data = GETDATE()
        WHERE ID_texto = @ID
    END
```

Once again thank you in advance for your help and time.

Comment: After Insert, you're using a trigger to update the same table that your trigger is on.  I would do this with Default constraints and/or computed columns instead.

Comment: I agree with @TabAlleman here. Your trigger logic is completely broken here too. If you ever insert more than 1 row your logic if not going to work correctly. You should avoid scalar variables and you should also be referencing the inserted and/or deleted tables in triggers.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are performing the following query simply to get the inserted row:

```
SELECT MAX(ID_texto) FROM dbo.textos
```

That won't work, as others have pointed out. If you insert more than one row at once, only the last in the set will be modified by the trigger.

Do a JOIN on the INSERTED table to get the new rows, then another JOIN on `semantickeyphrasetable(textos, *)` to get the tag values. Something like this:

```
USE Teste_TextMining
CREATE TRIGGER Noticia07032016 ON dbo.textos
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE T 
    SET tag = UPPER(K.keyphrase), data = GETDATE()
    FROM dbo.textos T
    JOIN INSERTED ON INSERTED.ID_texto = T.ID_texto
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT TOP 1 document_key, keyphrase 
        FROM semantickeyphrasetable(textos, *)
    ) K ON K.document_key=T.ID_texto
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Triggers will basically trigger once for each batch operation, so you should perform your logic based on this reality. This is also in SQL spirit, which favors (read as performs better) set based operations.

All inserted items are stored into a special table, called `inserted`, so you should join with this table to know what are the exact records that were touched:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Noticia07032016 ON dbo.textos
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ID INT
    SET @ID = (     SELECT MAX(ID_texto) FROM dbo.textos)

    DECLARE @tag NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @tag = (    SELECT TOP 1 keyphrase 
                    FROM semantickeyphrasetable(textos, *)
                    WHERE document_key=@ID)

    BEGIN
        UPDATE Dest 
        SET tag = UPPER(@tag)
        FROM dbo.textos Dest
            JOIN inserted I ON I.ID_texto = Dest.ID_texto
        WHERE ID_texto = @ID
    END
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Dest 
        SET data = GETDATE()
        FROM dbo.textos Dest
            JOIN inserted I ON I.ID_texto = Dest.ID_texto
        WHERE ID_texto = @ID
    END
END
```

The above is not tested, but should help you get an idea on how to proceed to actually update records that were inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Did this answer ever get solved?

If not, why not just add both updates in one line instead of having 2 BEGIN...END blocks?

```
CREATE TRIGGER Noticia07032016 ON dbo.textos
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @ID INT
  SET @ID = (     SELECT MAX(ID_texto) FROM dbo.textos)

  DECLARE @tag NVARCHAR(MAX)
  SET @tag = (    SELECT TOP 1 keyphrase 
                FROM semantickeyphrasetable(textos, *)
                WHERE document_key=@ID)

  BEGIN
      UPDATE Dest 
      SET tag = UPPER(@tag), data = GETDATE()
      FROM dbo.textos Dest
        JOIN inserted I ON I.ID_texto = Dest.ID_texto
      WHERE ID_texto = @ID
  END
END
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the below code. In your case I think the trigger is firing before semantickeyphrasetable TABLE insertion done. So updating nothing in first begin as @tag is empty.

Its better to put the trigger in child table.(If we need to update Parent table with child table data.)

```
    USE Teste_TextMining

    CREATE TRIGGER Noticia07032016 ON dbo.textos
    AFTER INSERT
    AS
    DECLARE @ID INT
        ,@tag NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @ID = ID_texto
    FROM INSERTED

    SET @tag = (
            SELECT TOP 1 keyphrase
            FROM semantickeyphrasetable(textos, *)
            WHERE document_key = @ID
            )

    UPDATE dbo.textos
    SET tag = UPPER(@tag)
        ,

    SET data = GETDATE()
    WHERE ID_texto = @ID
    GO
```

Note: When multiple insertion done, it will fail.

Comment: Same problem, the tag row is still returning null

Comment: Yes, it is because you are fetching the tag value before it gets inserted @XinkZ

Comment: Since you know this code isn't going to work correctly why not fix it so it can handle multiple row operations?

Comment: @SeanLange I assume it in case where only one row insertion occur.     Ex :While registration we will have only one insertion per one registration for some tables. at_downvotee

Comment: When writing triggers they should ALWAYS be able to handle multiple row operations. I have consultant friend who worked for a company that literally had to close their doors because all their triggers assumed only a single row. The cost to fix it was too much and the went out of business. It would not be difficult to convert your code here so it works for any number of rows.

Comment: @SeanLange yes off course you are right. But here he asked why it is not updating the first  begin. And just I had informed him a case where his code may get fails

Comment: So make it better not just get rid of the errors. Fix your code so it is set based and you will get a plus 1 from me.